# How to add new custom options with custom values on cart update?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, custom-options

I have a **custom HTML on cart page** with some ***checkboxes***.
I am getting All the selected checkboxes in my observer "**checkout_cart_update_items_before**" I am able to update cart item prices in this observer.

*Now **on cart update** I want to create these **selected checkboxes** as **Custom option** to cart items and display them with all items in cart.*

Following is the code that I have tried to create Custom options.

```
    $item->addOption(
                      array( 
                            'code'  => 'logo_options',
                            'value' => serialize($logo_positions),
                           )
                    );                      
    if ($logoOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('logo_options')) {                            
          $options = $item->getProductOptions();
          $options['logo_options'] = unserialize($logoOptions->getValue());
          item->setProductOptions($options);
    }
    $item->save();
```

Below is a screenshot of Cart.

---

[image]

Comment: You cannot add multiselect as a custom option to cart items.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Then what about custom options as selected checkboxes?

Comment: You can only show it as custom option title and its value.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya: What now? I have just added the code for adding custom option but only price in being updated those options are still not getting created to cart item and there are no errors.

Comment: If you are using Custom options then they should automatically be added to cart if selected. Can you add details about how and where you added checkboxes and what exactly you want to achieve? Will be better if you add screenshots of your cart page.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya: Ok so here is the link http://hemant.wcukdev.co.uk/dev7/wear/index.php/test-product.html
Add this product to cart and you will get logo option with in the cart. after checking this box you will get all its positions with respective prices. 

There are no for product but when a user selects the logo positions. these positions i need to be displayed as product's custom option on cart update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55053/discussion-between-wasiq-shahrukh-and-jaimin-sutariya).

Comment: Please suggest which extension you have user i wants this one.

Comment: @ravipatel : I am not using any plugin for this, it is a custom made functionality. Let me know your requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code to save your custom options' data.
You need to create arrays for each of the options you want to add to your product. I have used static data but you can do it with your dynamic data.

```
$logoOption = array(
    'label'                    => 'Logo Options',
    'option_value'             => 'My Logo',
    'value'                    => 'My Logo',
    'print_value'              => 'My Logo',
);
$locationOption = array(
    'label'                    => 'Location',
    'option_value'             => 'Right Breast',
    'value'                    => 'Right Breast',
    'print_value'              => 'Right Breast',
);
$value = array('logo_options'=> $logoOption, 'location' => $locationOption);
$value = serialize($value);
```

Now to set this data as Product options,
Use code,

```
$item->addOption(array('code'=> 'additional_options', 'product_id'=> $item->getProductId(), 'value'=> $value));
```

This will add your data to product as options. See screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Thank You! I just checked it and its working. Now I know what was missing.