# In Magento2 what is the place to override the quote?

Tags: magento2, overrides, quote, override-block, override-model

In Magento2, I want to modify the Quote. I want to add some custom attributes to the items and change the order of the items.

At what level should it be done, Model, Controller, Block? Please, specify why. What are the pros and cons.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add observer after adding to cart or cart refresh there you can add your custom attribute. follow [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163407/how-to-add-new-custom-options-with-custom-values-on-cart-update) question on cart update custom option

Comment: Thanks! Why don't you give an answer in the answer part?